# MongoDB shard key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've been thinking about selecting the best shard key (through a compound index) for my data and thought the combination of the document creation date combined with a customer no. (or invoice no.) would be a good combination. IF MongoDB would consider the customer no as a string backwards ie.:

```
90043 => 34009
90044 => 44009
90045 => 54009
etc.
```

Index on the The creation date would ensure that relatively new data are kept in memory and the backward customer no would help MongoDB to distribute the data/load across the cluster.

Is this a correct assumption? and if so... would I need to save my customer no reversed for it to be distributed the way I expect?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific question of "would I need to save my customer no reversed for it to be distributed the way I expect?", no - you would not.

Even with the relatively narrow spread of customer number values you listed, if you use `customerNumber` in your compound key, MongoDB will break apart the data into chunks and distribute these accordingly. As long as the data associated with `customerNumber` are relatively  evenly distributed (e.g., one user doesn't dominate the system), you will get the shard balancing you desire.

I would consider either your original choice (minus the string reversal) or Dan's choice (using the built-in ObjectId instead of timestamp) as good candidates for your compound key.

Comment: Provided that the nodes in my MongoDB cluster only can contain 3 customers each, I would expect the data sharding would differ like the following depending on which way the customer no is directed... is this wrong a wrong assumption?

**Forward** _Node 1:_ 80073 80074 80075 - _Node 2:_ 90073 90074 90075
**Reverse** _Node 1:_ 37008 37009 47008 - _Node 2:_ 47009 57008 57009

The "reverse" customer no would seem to avoid an undistributable hotspot.

Comment: The Balancer is in charge of placing chunks of a sharded collection and does so as it sees fit. I'm not sure you could limit or specify any particular pattern like "only 3 customers each." Regarding forward/backward, as long as the values are discrete, the range/distribution of the value makes no difference to the Balancer.

Comment: "only 3 customers each" was for the sake of the example.
What does it mean that "values are discrete"?
When speaking about a range, sorting is involved.
Reversing the customer no (looking at it like a string) would have a significant impact on how the values in the field would be sorted ... I just don't understand why it wouldn't affect how the data is sharded?

Comment: By "discrete" I mean distinct. It is true that reversing the string will affect how the data is sharded by how the config server breaks the data into chunks. The same would be true if you hashed the customer number. However, neither will make a difference in performance of the cluster over leaving the field alone. See for yourself: Set up a sample sharded system on your local machine, inject a bunch of data, and watch how the balancer moves chunks around (query the config server). Try it again with a different set of shard keys, etc.

Answer (score 0):

from what I have read in the documentation the MongoId is already time based.
Therfore you can add the _id to your compound key like this: (_id, customerid). If you don't need the date in your application, you can just drop the field which would save you some storage.

MongoDB stores the datasets recently used in memory. 
The index of a collection will always tried to be stored into RAM.

> When an index is too large to fit into RAM, MongoDB must read the
>   index from disk, which is a much slower operation than reading from
>   RAM. Keep in mind an index fits into RAM when your server has RAM
>   available for the index combined with the rest of the working set.

Hope this helps.

Cheers dan

Comment: I do need the created date and _id and customer no. would kinda serve the same purpose (being the unique identifier for the customer) though customer no. Would be in a human readable format usable on a website, in emails etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your thinking it that, somehow, you feel Node 1 would be faster than Node 2.  Unless the hardware is drastically different then Node 1 and Node 2 would be accessed equally fast and thus reversing the strings would not help you out.

The main issue I see has to do with the number of customers in your system.  This can lead to monotonic sharding wherein the last shard is the one always being hit and that can cause excessive splitting and migration.  If you have a large number of customers then there is no issue, otherwise you might want to add another key on top of the customer id and date fields to more evenly divide up your content.  I have heard of people using random identifiers, hashing the _id or using a GUID to overcome this issue.

Comment: I belive that node 1 and node 2 performs the same which is why I want new customers to be distributed evenly over the nodes... see my example in the comment to SethO.
A forward customer no would result in all new customers being on the same node. I would expect a reversed customer no to fan out much better.